# Cloth effect to boned model for XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, blender, physics-engine, kinect

I'm currently working in virtual dressing project using kinect. I'm using a dress model with bone created in blender and added that to xna, placed on the customer and controlled the product movements like hand, leg using the kinect skeleton data.

I would like to add some cloth physics effect to the model like flying and shaking. What would be a best way to accomplish this. I have surfed a lot and found that can be done using physics engine but no idea about which engine and how?

Can I create the cloth effect in blender and add that to xna? or else whether I need to add some engine like bullet and Physx inside xna and create that cloth effect manually.

Comment: You might want to research and learn [Verlet Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) as it can be quite effective for simulating cloth.

Comment: @newton1212 It seems like verlet integration provided for the 2d images most of the links which i found in my surf are mean that, and more over I have a 3d model created in blender that may have few animation, on those case applying verlet integration via code, Will It make any reaction? I don't think so

Comment: Yes, verlet integration is (afaik) the most common technique used to animate clothing, flags and such things (even jelly-like objects can be made). Of course you can't use an 'effect' in blender and add that to xna, unless you mean saving an animation and use that (but your question suggests you want the cloth to be interactive).

Comment: @MonKeePoo you got the point. for the past one week trying with the some nvidia physx samples but it does not have any direct solution, working on moderate that according to the requirement, lets see. reason to not touch the verlet integration is, swear it will suck the time, it will be like developing a new engine, if I could not find anything appropriate,then have to get into that, no other go...

Comment: The main idea is not that difficult: if youre an experienced coder, i estimate that you can implement something in an afternoon or two. Just try to work out something from pseudocode and tweak some parameters until you get a nice result. The intersection might be more difficult, though.

Comment: yeah It seems. Now trying with some 3d engines (unity and unreal)... hope will get a result soon. Thanks for your valuable comments @MonKeePoo